# wordpress "pods custom content types and fields plugin" edit.php new button next to relationship field

Tags: wordpress

How to add a button next to the relationship field, which on click will open a new popup with the selected type, then after adding a new record, to select that record.

[image: Choosing Relationship]

Is it possible with pods ?

Comment: Can you provide more details on this? What is a relationship field, which records are you refering to? What is pods? What have you tried/where are you stuck?

Comment: I want something like http://www.ilian.io/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/django-admin.png in Python Django.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? There are many different ways to solve this, e.g. by javascript, by modifying the "pods..." plugin or maybe even by creating a new plugin. What should this button do?

Comment: As the above image django-admin.png ilustrates, a button with plus icon should be put, that button must open a popup that loads: post-new.php?post_type=piece, after closing the popup, the created piece item should be selected inside the dropdown (relationship).
What I ask here is if this thing is already implemented in the plugin, or should I improvise ?